# no module named venv when installing python3.6 from source

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, centos7

I've installed `python3.6` from source on `CentOS7` linux system, using configure as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash
./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install --enable-shared  --enable-ipv6 --with-install --prefix=/home/$USER/Documents/reporter-web/python --rpath=/home/development/Documents/reporter-web/python/lib
make altinstall
```

When running the command `/path/to/python/bin/python3.6 -m venv venv`, 
Before using `rpath` it was returning a can't find shared lib error, after using it now it returns `no module named venv` when I try to create a new `venv` .. any help?

Comment: can you show example of command which is returning you the `venv` error? Also is there any reason to install it manually instead of via `yum`?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko check updated question for the command, and I can't use yum because this server is completely offline and can't have access to the internet.